# Creating point in shapefile from latitude/longitude using GeoTools?

Tags: java, geotools

I m new to geotools and i find bit difficult to plot a point using the latitude and longitude values. can any one heple me out to solve my problem.

```
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory():
SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(TYPE); 
Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude));
featureBuilder.add(point);
```

but this code is not working properly. could any one explain why..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, you miss to define a feature type: In GeoTools (and not only), you will first need to define the structure of your data, *ie* the Feature type (~ schema). For this you have to use `SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder` that will help to build the feature type, afterwhat you will be able to construct properly the `SimpleFeatureBuilder` based on the featuretype you defined before (the `TYPE` argument in your code)

Create the Simple Feature Type (structure of your data):

```
SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder b = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();

//set the name
b.setName( "MyFeatureType" );

//add a geometry property
b.setCRS( DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84 ); // set crs first
b.add( "location", Point.class ); // then add geometry

//build the type
final SimpleFeatureType TYPE = b.buildFeatureType();
```

Create the feature(s) using the feature type previously defined

```
SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(TYPE);
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude));
featureBuilder.add(point);
SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature( "fid.1" ); // build the 1st feature
```

Next step, you can create a feature collection, using the feature(s) you defined before:

```
DefaultFeatureCollection featureCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection("internal",TYPE);
featureCollection.add(feature); //Add feature 1
// Add feature 2, 3, etc
```

I recommend you to follow examples from http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/main This will also help to understand how geospatial data is structured in Geotools

For the plotting part, i suggest you to familiarize with the geotools rendering module: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/render/map.html.

Comment: Could u be more specific. since i am new to geotools i don't know what is TYPE. for creating a point can u give me a clear coding..??

Comment: I've added few code to explain you the 1st step you need to follow that is to define the structure of your data, named _FeatureType_. The `SimpleFeatureBuilder` will use the featureType you defined, afterwhat you can create each of the features you need. I highly recommend you to look more to the geotools documentation which provides good examples, also for rendering/ploting the data once is prepared.

Comment: i tried your code. i am getting error on this line.. `SimpleFeatureType TYPE = b.buildFeatureType();`

Comment: but i am clear with your explanation.

Comment: my apologies, they were some typos in the code i've sent. Now you can check it works!

Comment: Should the latitude and longitude values be in degree format or in LAT/LONG format. any idea

Comment: It depends on the CRS you choose in your feature type. In the above example, i've specified WGS84 which is in long/lat.

Comment: i have used the code. there are no errors. but i couldn't find any point on the LAT/LONG provided..! shall i paste u the overall code of my project.?

Comment: in which format your coordinates are provided?

Comment: its in Double..!

Comment: If you have coordinates they are x/y (or y/x). No problem if the values are in Double, it's generally the case. You should identify in your file if they correspond to lon/lat or lat/long, or x/y of a particular projection system If you have a doubt, add a sample of coordinates in your post.

Comment: Could you please check this..? [Complete coding](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115243/create-a-point-on-a-map-using-geotools)